# Convert JSON output from API to list of HTML links

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I query the following API.

```
var json_obj;
$.getJSON("https://46il4vpccl.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/api/secblogfeed/Threatpost", function (data) {
json_obj = data;
});
```

I can then see the output using the following approach:

```
alert(json_obj.Items[0].title);
alert(json_obj.Items[0].link)
```

What I would like to do is return a list of all `title` and `link` as a hyperlink as follows by expanding on the code above:

(Desired output HTML would be like this on a web page).

```
<p><a href="link string here">title string here</a></p>
<p><a href="link string here">title string here</a></p>
etc
```

I have tried various ways of looping through this data but would like to learn how to do this efficiently. Thanks for any help.

Comment: loop throught item array and generate html using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a loop through the `Items` property of the response to build the required HTML. The most succinct way of doing this would be to use `map()`, like this:

```
$.getJSON("https://46il4vpccl.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/api/secblogfeed/Threatpost", function(data) {
  var html = data.Items.map(function(item) {
    return `<p><a href="${item.link}">${item.title}</a></p>`;
  });
  $('#yourContainingElement').append(html);
});
```

Also note that I am getting a CORS error when making a request to that domain. I'd suggest you check that the request works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to map the original object to a new filtered object like this

```
let list = json_obj.Items.map(e=>{
  return {title:e.title,link:e.link}
});
```

You can then use a for loop to generate elements for each element of this object as

```
function generateElement(item) {
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href",item.link);
    a.innerText = a.title;
    p.appendChild(a);
    return p;
}
```